# Code choosing not to be asynchronous

Tags: swift, asynchronous, alamofire

I have a function which grabs a couple variables from an online JSON, one of those being the Approved variable which is set to `"true"`. When I call the function, the first time I will get the "Denied" alert since the Approved variable does not have a value since the code is not asynchronous, but no matter what I do I can't get it to work. It's only until the second time that it has the previous value saved and goes to the Success alert.

The code:

```
@IBAction func approveuser(_ sender: AnyObject) {
theplace = place //Saving variable.

Alamofire.request("https://example.com?variable=\(variable)&requested=\(self.place)").responseJSON{ response in
if let JSON = response.result.value{
let json = JSON as! NSDictionary
Approved = json["Approved"] as! String
LoadedVersion = json["version"] as! String
}
}



if(AppVersion != LoadedVersion){
self.showalert("Update Required", message: "Please update the app", confirm: "Okay")
return
}

if(Approved == "true"){
self.showalert("Approved!", message: "Success", confirm: "Okay")
}else{
self.showalert("Denied!", message: "Denied", confirm: "Okay")
}
}
```

I have tried placing `DispatchQueue.main.async {` wherever I can in the code but it still does not want to work no matter where I put it.

Comment: You should really embrace the asynchronous nature and do your stuff in the callback. If you really must wait, try using a semaphore as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38758847/14955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where put the codes for asynchronous on main queue?

I think like below be work as your intended.

```
@IBAction func approveuser(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    theplace = place //Saving variable.

    Alamofire.request("https://example.com?variable=\(variable)&requested=\(self.place)").responseJSON{ response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value{
            let json = JSON as! NSDictionary
            Approved = json["Approved"] as! String
            LoadedVersion = json["version"] as! String
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if(AppVersion != LoadedVersion){
                self.showalert("Update Required", message: "Please update the app", confirm: "Okay")
                return
            }

            if(Approved == "true"){
                self.showalert("Approved!", message: "Success", confirm: "Okay")
            }else{
                self.showalert("Denied!", message: "Denied", confirm: "Okay")
            }
        }
    }
}
```